# Android listview: Resource Not Found Exception

Tags: android, exception, listview, android-layout

I've got problem with Listview in Android.
Then I try to set adapter to a listview I got Resource Not Found Exception.

My code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> list;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        list.add("first");

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.CheckpointList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.CheckpointList, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And in my main.xml I've got:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/CheckpointList" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

I've tried to clean and refesh project - no effects...

How to solve this problem?

Cheers.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The resource you hand over to the ArrayAdapter should not be the id of the ListView. It should be the `textViewResourceId` - which is basically which TextView-layout-id you want your items, in the list, to be rendered as.

One of the standards is e.g. `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Here's an example of a simple ListView:

```
public class ListviewExample extends Activity
{
    private ListView listView;
    private String listView_data[] = {"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
        // By using setAdapter method in listview we add the string array to the ListView.
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , listView_data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The ressource you hand over to the ArrayAdapter should not be the id of the listview. It should be the layout ressource of the textview in the listview. Look at the documentation:  [ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List objects)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29)